# CISCO ASA: threat-detection vs. IPS module

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

There is threat-detection mechanism is CISCO ASA. We can configure different rate limits and actions. Also our ASA 5525-X has enabled integrated IPS module. We can setup protection rules on IPS. What is the best practise of security implementation: threat-detection or IPS, or both?

Comment: What is stopping you from just using both now?  As long as you have the performance overhead, more protection is better, right?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible I would go for IPS module, it s one of the best security products available on the market. As long as you have the license just fine tune it and use it accordingly to your needs.

For any other scenarios when IPS not available, threat-statistics will prove helpful.

Comment: I have to disagree that Cisco's IPS is one of the best security product on the market. It really cannot compete with SourceFire/Snort (ok, ok it's now Cisco...), Radware, F5 and even PaloAlto.

Answer (score 0):

Threat-detection is just gathering statistics (with possibility to shun attacker's ip).

Comment: If I am right, you can block only hosts that produce only scanning activity. All other information - statistical.